# Google cloud vision- get JSON error response from OCR request

Tags: json, xamarin.android, ocr, google-cloud-vision

I'm new at using google cloud API so please forgive me if I ask any silly question. I want to try develop android app by Xamarin c# to do OCR for Thai language, so my idea is to  and I want to get OCR result from my photo.
This's my json request

```
{"requests": [
{"image":{"content":"3QGzdykwB2MZPcpx...."},
"imageContext": {"languageHints":["th"]},
"features": [{"type":"DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION"}]}]}
```

But the result that I got is

```
"error": {
"code": 14,
"message": "Service temporarily unavailable. Error processing features."}
```

What wrong with this? Anyone please give some suggestion. Thank you.

Comment: getting same error... any resolution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have not provided the source code,let me assume that you are using the [GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/vision/face-detection)

The main reason for the above exception is that the face annotations in the below code is null. You can just update the following code as your requirement

```
if (response.getFaceAnnotations() == null) {
  throw new IOException(
      response.getError() != null
          ? response.getError().getMessage()
          : "Unknown error getting image annotations");
}
```